# add fields to joomla 3.8 login form

Tags: module, joomla3.0

I need to add more fields for the login form in Joomla. I am a school teacher and I know my students get confused or forget their username or password. I would like to add 2 lists, one that will chose class section and the other will list the students inside that class and that way the student will only select their name from the list then the student only have to enter the correct password.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Possible to do like that but it's required custom code in your joomla login module.

Comment: Thanks for the advise but how i can add custom code to that?